# How to display footer image with 100% width in all screen sizes

Tags: html, css

I have an image which I want to display as the background image of footer. It should be showing at 100% width of all screen sizes but at present it is displaying correctly in small screens whereas in large screens it is getting displayed only in the center of the screen with both the sides left vacant which I dont want.

Here is the Css that I have used to set background image of footer Div:

```
.footer-shadow {
    position:relative;
    height: 237px;
    margin-top:0px;
    width: 100%;
    background: url('../img/new_images/footer-bg.png') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    color: gray;
}
```

Please help me to make footer responsive so that the image adjusts with all screen sizes.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the image to be 100% wide at all times, use the following CSS

```
.footer-shadow {
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

This automatically makes the **width** of the background image **100%**, and scales the height accordingly. You currently use `background-size: contain;`, which scales the image to "the largest size such that both its width and its height can fit inside the content area."

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
background-size: contain;
```

by

```
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: cover does **not** make the background image 100% wide. `background-size: cover;`"scales the background image to be as large as possible so that the background area is completely covered by the background image. Some parts of the background image may not be in view within the background positioning area" This results in possible cropping.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `background-size:cover;` property which stretches your image to cover size (includes cropped area) but might not show up correctly in many browsers for which you need to add in additional webkit parameters for firefox and IE like this:

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
```